# wp_query serialised array

Tags: wp-query

I have seen various ways to do this but none working 100% for me. I have a dropdown/select menu and users can choose multiple choices. This then sends an array of values that I want to query.

Either I can query each one individually but this isn't realistic because the array has many values and I would have to then cater for every single option eg:

```
'meta_query'    => array(
    'relation'      => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'       => 'location',
        'value'     => 'Melbourne',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'location',
        'value'     => 'Sydney',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    )
)
```

I also tried to serialise the array like below, but this only works if I choose one option from the select menu. As soon as select multiple options I get an empty array as the response.

```
'value'   => serialize( $locations ),
'compare' => 'LIKE'
```

Finally, I tried a regex example I found but couldn't get that going either.

```
$field_value = sprintf( '^%1$s$|s:%2$u:"%1$s";', $locations, strlen( $locations ) );
'value' => $field_value,
'compare' => 'REGEXP'
```

Comment: If the meta value is a serialized string of an array like `array( 'Melbourne', 'Sydney' )`, then `'value' => '"(Melbourne|Sydney)"', 'compare' => 'REGEXP'` would work. But then have you considered using a custom taxonomy named `location` instead?

Comment: @SallyCJ, seriously. You are a legend! That works great. I wouldn't be able to create a taxonomy in this case, don't want to bore you with details! But, your solution is perfect. Would you be able to add it as an answer so I can mark as accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, if the meta value is a serialized string of an array like `array( 'Melbourne', 'Sydney' )`, then `'value' => '"(Melbourne|Sydney)"', 'compare' => 'REGEXP'` would work.

So there's no need for a complex regular expression pattern, and your `meta_query` could look like so where `$locations` is an array of locations:

```php
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'location',
        'value'   => '"(' . implode( '|', $locations ) . ')"',
        'compare' => 'REGEXP',
    ),
),
```